# coq: Prove Theorem negb_is_not from Tutorial

Tags: coq

There is a point in proving

```
Theorem negb_is_not : (forall a, Is_true (negb a) <-> (~(Is_true a))).
```

from this [tutorial](https://coq.inria.fr/tutorial-nahas) in Coq where I am stuck. This is the case when `False` is left to prove as "False cannot be proven". How do I cope with that?

```
Theorem negb_is_not : (forall a, Is_true (negb a) <-> (~(Is_true a))).
Proof.
  intros A.
  unfold iff.
  refine (conj _ _).
  case A.
  simpl.
  intros H.
  destruct H. 
  intros H.
  simpl in H.
  simpl.
  unfold not.
  intros.
  exact H0.
  unfold not.
  intros H.
  case A.
  simpl.
  destruct H.
  case A.
  simpl.
  exact I.
  simpl.
  Focus 2.
  simpl.
  exact I.
```

I think I just missed some little important thing in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some rewrites, I was able to write this proof:

```
Theorem negb_is_not : (forall a, Is_true (negb a) <-> (~(Is_true a))).
Proof.
  intros A.
  unfold iff.
  refine (conj _ _).
    case A.
      simpl.
      intros H.
      case H.

      simpl.
      intros.
      unfold not.
      intros.
      exact H0.

    case A.
      simpl.
      unfold not.
      intros.
      refine (H _).
      exact I.

      simpl.
      unfold not.
      intros.
      exact I.
Qed.
```

Comment: A few remarks: `case` seems to operate only on the conclusion, you can use `destruct` instead which operates on the conclusion and the hypotheses; instead of `unfold iff. refine (conj _ _).`, you can use the more natural `split.`